# Jekyll and Minima with Two Fonts?

Tags: jekyll, minima

I'm trying to get Jekyll to use two fonts, one for headings, and one for body text. To this end, I've copied the entire _sass folder to the root of my site, then changed \_sass\minima\_base.scss to include definitions for both fonts...

```
/**
  * Basic styling
 */
body {
  font: $base-font-weight #{$base-font-size}/#{$base-line-height} $base-font-family;
  color: $text-color;
  background-color: $background-color;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "kern" 1;
     -moz-font-feature-settings: "kern" 1;
       -o-font-feature-settings: "kern" 1;
          font-feature-settings: "kern" 1;
  font-kerning: normal;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/**
 * Set `margin-bottom` to maintain vertical rhythm
 */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,
p, blockquote, pre,
ul, ol, dl, figure,
%vertical-rhythm {
  font: $heading-font-weight #{$heading-font-size}/#{$heading-line-height} $heading-font-family;
  margin-bottom: $spacing-unit / 2;
}
```

Then in \_sass\minimua.scss, I changed the styling for the base font, then added the heading font:

```
$base-font-family: serif, Times, "Times New Roman";
$base-font-size:   16px !default;
$base-font-weight: 400 !default;
$small-font-size:  $base-font-size * 0.875 !default;
$base-line-height: 1.5 !default;

$heading-font-family: sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial;
$heading-font-size:   16px !default;
$heading-font-weight: 400 !default;
$heading-line-height: 1.5 !default;
```

I also created \_sass\my_overrides.scss which looks like this:
    @charset "utf-8";

```
// Define defaults for each variable.

$base-font-family: serif, Times, "Times New Roman";
$heading-font-family: san-serif, Helvetica, Arial;
```

But as far as I can tell, the fonts are switched in their use (screenshot below). And I'm probably forgetting something because this whole process is so complex.

So my question is:
How do I get two fonts working with Jekyll, serif for body, san-serif for headings?

I suppose I could also ask if Jekyll has a dual-font facility built in and if not, why not? But perhaps that sounds belligerent? (It's not meant to.)

[Screenshot showing switched fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8S1V.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the font in Jekyll Minima (default) theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54138066/changing-the-font-in-jekyll-minima-default-theme)

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to split your css to target each separately, like this:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font: $heading-font-weight #{$heading-font-size}/#{$heading-line-height} $heading-font-family;
    margin-bottom: $spacing-unit / 2;
}

p, blockquote, pre,
ul, ol, dl, figure,
%vertical-rhythm {
    font: $base-font-weight #{$base-font-size}/#{$base-font-height} $$base-font-family;
    margin-bottom: $spacing-unit / 2;
}
```

Comment: I'm very new to jekyll. Would this be in minima.scss or _base.scss? Does it need to be in both?

Comment: Put it in base if that is the file that overrides the default styles. Otherwise I would suggest creating a _app.scss file you can use strictly for customization as to not interfere with the default minima packaging/scss files.

Comment: To be honest, I gave up. I managed to get the font changed to something readable (serif) and now I don't wanna touch again because I don't wanna spend hours trying to fix it (again). I can't find a guide or tutorial for which files do what in Jekyll or how to make this kind of change. I think Jekyll was designed to use only one font, so this is now on the back burner. I'll just keep an eye out for something else that's more plug-n-play. But thanks for asking.